# What is the best way to use a HyperlinkedModelSerializer with a OneToOneField in Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

What is the best way to use a HyperlinkedModelSerializer with a OneToOneField?

I have two models (A, B)
A and  B have a one-to-one association.
Model B use's the A_id as it's own primary key value, which is the default setting.

I'm able to create records for resource A, but when I attempt to create them for resource B using the url for A in place of the primary key I get the following error:
a_id cannot be null.

My url is something like:
HTTPIE
http -f POST http://example.com/b/ field_1=abc a=http://example.com/a/1/

I even tried:
http -f POST http://example.com/b/ field_1=abc a=http://example.com/a/1/ a_id=1
and received the same error.

```
--- Views ---

class SampleMetadataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SampleMetadata.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleMetadataSerializer


class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer


--- Serializers ---


class SampleMetadataSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    sample = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='sample-detail', read_only=True, many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = SampleMetadata
        fields = ['url', 'color', 'weight', 'length', 'height', 'sample']


class SampleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    sample_metadata = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='sample_metadata-detail', many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'location', 'sample_metadata']


--- Models ---

class Sample(models.Model):
    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission, related_name='samples', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.original_file_name

class SampleMetadata(models.Model):
    sample = models.OneToOneField(Sample, related_name='sample_metadata', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField()
    weight = models.CharField()
    length = models.CharField()
    height = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sample
```

Comment: Please post your serializer, views, models and urls, question is very ambiguous right now.

Comment: I added the info you requested to the original post.